# Long select list options aren't visible on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have an html select list with an option that needs to be a long string of text. This is fine in my desktop browser but my iPhone crops the option text. Is there a way around this without shorting the text?

http://jsfiddle.net/fC83D/2/

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">This is too long on an iPhone and the text gets cropped</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you reword the option to be shorter or make the long option wrap in mobile view?

Comment: What do you mean 'is there a way'? Are you after a technical solution here, some Javascript or something? What exactly is it you're looking for in an answer here?

Comment: You could replace the <select> with a bunch of <input type=radio> .. the text will get fully displayed that way. The downside of course is that they get displayed in full, rather than hidden in a <select> control.